# What is causing OutOfMemoryError when migrating a jdk8 build to jdk9?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, maven-3, java-9

I am migrating a poc of junit 4 -> junit 5 from jdk 8 -> jdk 9...

The build of [junit-poc](https://github.com/jactor-rises/junit-poc/tree/jigsaw-poc-wip) fails in my jigsaw branch with an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. I can run these tests from my idea (IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1), but the error comes when building with maven (and the tests are not executed).

`mvn --version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /Library/maven
Java version: 9-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_NO, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

`java -version`:

```
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+167)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+167, mixed mode)
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.jactor-rises</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-poc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>junit-poc</name>
    <url>https://github.com/jactor-rises/junit-poc</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>4.12.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

from maven build:

```
[INFO] Running com.github.jactorrises.junit.PocBeanJupiterTest
[INFO] Running com.github.jactorrises.junit.PocBeanTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.391 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-30T13:53:18+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/48M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] OutOfMemoryError -> [Help 1]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.hugeCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.newCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:180)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:147)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:512)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.MultipleFailureException.getLocalizedMessage(MultipleFailureException.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$CloseableCloser.run(ForkStarter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils$1.call(CommandLineUtils.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:626)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:279)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1077)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:907)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:563)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

This is giving me a headache...
It works fine in IntelliJ and as the stack trace shows, it is originating from the `AbstractStringBuilder` from inside the surefire-plugin. These are the artefacts being used:

```
<artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>...
<artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>...
<artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>...
```

I am using surefire-plugin version 2.20. Has anyone experienced a similar error?

This is a pain in the $#$... I have upgraded java 9 ea to build 172 and mockito core to 2.8.9. I have all the latest versions, but no luck so far... Suggestions are appriciated.

Full source code: [jigsaw-junit-poc](https://github.com/jactor-rises/junit-poc/tree/jigsaw-poc-wip)

Comment: this seems to be a maven issue. it works in intellij, and when running with `mvn clean install -X`, only apache.maven and codehaus.plexus is part of the stack trace (except for java internals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved itself with some new java versions or surefire-plugin version

I am now using openjdk 13 and surefire-plugin 2.22.0

Answer (score 1):

Java 9 changed its String representation from chars to using bytes. I assume the answer lies here. Do you use a lot of special characters somewhere?

Comment: intriguing possibility... i do not think so... how can i check? you are very welcome to check my code on [github](https://github.com/jactor-rises/junit-poc/tree/jigsaw-poc-wip)

Comment: Take a heap dump of the Maven process whe it crashes. (Put XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in your Maven opts.)

Comment: ok... is there anything particular i am looking for? i have no experience in reading output from maven while doing a heap dump... the resulted log is huge...

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter indeed int was changed, but that should *reduce* the memory used by Strings, not increase it.

Comment: do you have any other suggestions? please take a look at the fiddle of my heap dump: (http://refiddle.com/m17y)